# How to get rid of table borders in markdown?

Tags: html, css, markdown

This is my markdown code

```markdown
| Time         | Length        | Speed              | Mass         |    
|--------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------|
| Millisecond  | Millimetre    | Kilometre per hour | Milligram    |   
| Second       | Centimetre    | Foot per second    | Gram         |  
| Minute       | Inch          | Miles per hour     | Ounce        |     
| Hour         | Foot          | Knot               | Pound        |  
| Day          | Yard          | Metre per second   | Kilogram     |  
| Week         | Metre         |                    | Us ton       |  
| Month        | Kilometre     |                    | Tonne        |  
| Year         | Mile          |                    | Imperial ton |  
| Decade       | Nautical mile |                    |              |  
| Century      |               |                    |              |  
| Millennium   |               |                    |              |
```

Output:

| Time | Length | Speed | Mass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Millisecond | Millimetre | Kilometre per hour | Milligram |
| Second | Centimetre | Foot per second | Gram |
| Minute | Inch | Miles per hour | Ounce |
| Hour | Foot | Knot | Pound |
| Day | Yard | Metre per second | Kilogram |
| Week | Metre |  | Us ton |
| Month | Kilometre |  | Tonne |
| Year | Mile |  | Imperial ton |
| Decade | Nautical mile |  |  |
| Century |  |  |  |
| Millennium |  |  |  |

I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that the table has no borders.

Comment: I do not think it is possible since it is just a *markdown* and has no *CSS* in it.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I think he means in markdown.

Comment: It kind of depends, what markdown you are using, and where. In Stackoverflow only a very limited subset of HTML markup is allowed, but generally Markdown allows all HTML tags to be used in it, including `<style>`. This would allow you to define style options globally or for specific tables using CSS selectors.

Comment: @MMDM Yeah I only realised that as soon as I posted the link (I think I was distracted by the original table representation :) ) and I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no mechanism in Markdown itself to hide table borders. You can override table CSS styles for generated HTML, but that will work only if you have access to CSS.

For services like Github where CSS styles are predefined by service owner and cannot be overriden the table borders simply cannot be hidden.

Answer (score 14):

You can try to add a `<style>` tag at the top of your markdown file with rules to remove the border on `<td>` and `<tr>` elements.

But unfortunately I noticed it will only work locally on a preview.
Github [sanitizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) the inline style and script tags

```
<style>
td, th {
   border: none!important;
}
</style>


| Time         | Length        | Speed              | Mass         |
| ------------ | ------------- | ------------------ | ------------ |
| -Millisecond | Millimetre    | Kilometre per hour | Milligram    |
| Second       | Centimetre    | Foot per second    | Gram         |
| Minute       | Inch          | Miles per hour     | Ounce        |
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why does not it work on GitHub site?

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
   border: none;
}
blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>

| Column One    | Column Two    |                                                                                                                                                   
| ---           | ---           |                                                                                                                                                   
| data cell one | data cell two |
```

And you will obtain a nice, function table with all borders of all cells.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what the OP asked for...